# Image name uploaded into database. but i cant find the image in path folder

Tags: database, codeigniter

```
public function payment_confirmation($invoice_id = 0 )
{   
    $data['get_sitename'] = $this->model_settings->sitename_settings();
    $data['get_footer'] = $this->model_settings->footer_settings();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('invoice_id_input','Invoice id','required|integer');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount_input','Amount Transfered','required|integer');

    if($this->form_validation->run()    ==  FALSE)
    {
        if($this->input->post('invoice_id_input'))
        {
            $data['invoice_id'] =set_value('invoice_id_input');
        }else{  
                $data['invoice_id'] = $invoice_id;
            }
        $this->load->view('customer/form_payment_confirmation',$data);
    }else{
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 2000;
        $config['max_width']  = 2000;
        $config['max_height']  = 2000;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $upload_image = $this->upload->data();
        $userfile = array(
        'bukti_trnsfr'  => set_value('userfile'));

        $is_valid = $this->model_customer->mark_invoice_paid_confirmed(set_value('invoice_id_input'),set_value('amount_input'),$userfile);
            if ($is_valid)
            {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Terima Kasih, Produk Yang Anda Pesan Akan Segera Kami Proses');
                    redirect('customer/shopping_history');
            }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Jumlah Nominal Salah, Silahkan Coba Lagi ');
                    redirect('customer/payment_confirmation/'.set_value('invoice_id_input'));
                }

         }
}
```

This is the controller for user to confirm the payment. User should upload image as evidence of money transfer in my e-commerce system. I got this problem, the image is not in the folder but the image name is saved in the database table. Please help!

Comment: well you're uploading the image, but regardless of checking if the image is uploaded, you're saving the data to the database. You need to catch the upload exceptions and then process it database operations. Follow what @Shyam said in the answer for the image upload debugging.

Comment: after this line `$upload_image = $this->upload->data();` add this and post output `print_r($upload_image);die;`

Answer (score 0):

Please find below mentioned solution for the same. It will help you.

Append `FCPATH` to your upload directory path like mentioned below.

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'assets/uploads/';
```

You need to add input file name in `do_upload()`

```
$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
```

Also you need to check that image is uploaded on server or not before saving name to database.

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
     $userfile = array('bukti_trnsfr'  => set_value('userfile'));
}else{
     $userfile = array('bukti_trnsfr'  => '');
}
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: not works sir. do you have email? i can send the file to you :/

Comment: Can you check error log in `application/logs` folder and share output

Comment: If you need more help you can share you code here https://codebunk.com/b/512151751/

Comment: Open above link and copy your code and paste it on editor

Answer (score 0):

If you have use ubuntu plateform or any server then permission of this folder then after try to upload image because its permission issue